# how to update one table based on another table ID codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables, first table is directly associated with the second table. I'm using codeigniter and mysql as my database system.

My first table called `exam` and its structure on below picture:

[image: exam_tbl]

This is my second table called `exam_assign_classes`:

[image: exam_assign_tbl]

How do I update the second table based on first table id. Sometimes in the edit page a user can add assigned batch or remove number of batch. I have tried counting numbers of rows with matching ids and delete those from second table and then re-insert it but it seems so bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('`exam_id` IN (SELECT `exam_id` FROM `exam_assign_classes `)', NULL, FALSE);
$this->db->update('exam', $data);
```

Comment: actually i need to update the second table exam_assign_classes and it will have many rows associated  with exam_id. I have tried your solution but nothing happens. I am gonna posting my modal and controller code for update the exam record. Please review my code

Answer (score 0):

and this is my updated version of code where i placed bunch of database task in one update condition to update the exam assign table.

View:

```html
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <?php echo get_phrase('select_batchs'); ?></span>
  <select class="form-control" name="assigned_batch[]"  data-plugin="select2" multiple>
    <?php 
foreach($program_list as $program): 
$batch_list = $this->crud_model->get_batchs_by_program_id($program['program_id']);
?>
    <optgroup label="<?php echo $program['name']; ?>">
      <?php foreach($batch_list as $batch): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $batch['batch_id']; ?>" <?php foreach($assigned_batchs as $assignedRow){ if($assignedRow['batch_id'] == $batch['batch_id']) echo 'selected';} ?>><?php echo $batch['batch_name']; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </optgroup>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</div>
```

model:

```html
public function delete_associated_exam_assign($exam_id = '')
{
$this->db->where('exam_id', $exam_id);
$this->db->delete('exam_assign_classes');
return true;
}

public function insert_associated_exam_assign($data2){
$this->db->insert('exam_assign_classes', $data2);
return true;
}
```

```html
if($param1 == 'do_update'){
$data['name']       = $this->input->post('exam_title');
$data['start_date'] = $this->input->post('start');
$data['end_date']   = $this->input->post('end');
$data['status']     = $this->input->post('status');
if(isset($_POST['is_entrance'])):
$data['entrance_exam'] = $this->input->post('is_entrance');
endif;
$exam_id = $param2;

// update exam table
$this->crud_model->update_exam_details($exam_id, $data);

// update exam assign table
/*First of all delete all those associated rows with matching ids*/
$this->crud_model->delete_associated_exam_assign($exam_id);
/*insert newly assign classes*/
foreach($this->input->post('assigned_batch[]') as $batchs){
$data2['exam_id'] = $exam_id;
$data2['batch_id'] = $batchs;
$this->crud_model->insert_associated_exam_assign($data2);
}

$this->session->set_flashdata('flash_message' , get_phrase('data_updated'));
redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/exam_list/', 'refresh');
}
```

From above code i can achieve what i really need. But i am doing deleting and insert rows while updating fields on exam assign table. But it show down my app performance. so, is it a good practice or not to update the database ??